# Bitrix: количество элементов, выводимых в одной строке таблицы равное единице

Tags: php, битрикс

Использую компонент каталог, которому необходимо поставить количество элементов, выводимых в одной строке таблицы равным 1, просто когда я ставлю в настройках инфоблока 1, то почему-то выводятся все элементы, как исправить?

Comment: А какое отношение количество элементов в строке имеет к количеству выводимых элементов?

Comment: В смысле какое? В настройке компонента, если ставить количество элементов, выводимых в одной строке,допустим пять элементов, то выведется именно пять http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1462207983/91173acf/12521153.png . А проблема, повторюсь в том, что если поставить 1, то выводятся почему-то все

Comment: `params` вызова компонента приложите, пожалуйста?

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но я уже решил путём редактирования файла template

Answer (score 1):

Компонент с шаблоном по умолчанию выводит элементы таблицей: сколько строк и сколько элементов в каждой строке. Если код шаблона компонента нарушен, то этот принцип вывода таблицей может испортиться, и придется редактировать шаблон вывода компонента.